# Delete records in Oracle based on the date column

Tags: oracle

I am trying to delete records which are older 20 days or 1 year based on one date field .

In mysql, I can do

```
DELETE FROM Table_name
WHERE Date_column < DATEADD(day,-20,GETDATE())
```

```
DELETE FROM Table_name
WHERE Date_column < DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
```

Does Oracle have any way like Add_month() to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
delete from table_name
where date_column < trunc(sysdate) - 20;

delete from table_name
where date_column < add_months(trunc(sysdate), -12);
```